# Creating Rails objects for two models from one controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to achieve a flow where a user can view an overview/description of a newsletter, and then fill out a form with their email and subscribe. More specifically, a potential subscriber would:

- Navigate to `newsletters/:id/overview` and see an overview of a newsletter
- Fill out a form with their email and subscribe
- And then a new `Subscriber` (id, email) *and* a new `Subscription` (id, subscriber_id, newsletter_id) would be created.

Given that this flow cuts across three different models, I'm trying to figure out the "right/best" way to create a `Subscriber` and `Subscription`. Where I'm stuck is that I currently have the request from the form going to a `newsletter#subscribe` action, but I'm wondering at this point if I should:

- Create the subscriber and subscription directly within the method,
- Call the `subscriber#create` and `subscription#create` methods (from what I've read, calling actions across controllers isn't recommended)
- Create modules for creating a subscriber and subscription (haven't done this before, but a few Stackoverflow threads discuss it)
- Have the form request instead go to a `subscriber#create` action
- Or something else?

Here are some files:

newsletters/overview.html.erb

```
<h2>Subscribe:</h2>
<%= form_with scope: :subscriber, url: newsletter_subscribe_path do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :email %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

newsletters_controller.rb

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
  def subscribe
    # ???
  end
end
```

One note: I currently don't have my `subscription` routes nested under `subscriber` or `newsletter`, since they pertain to both. I'm not sure if changing that would simplify this.

**EDIT:**

**newsletter.rb**

```
class Newsletter < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :publisher
    has_many :posts
    has_many :subscriptions
end
```

**subscriber.rb**

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subscriptions
end
```

**subscription.rb**

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscriber
  belongs_to :newsletter
end
```

Comment: You need to share your model code as well to understand how they are related.

Comment: @AmitPatel Updated.

Comment: There is no 'correct' answer, you can create any models in any controller actions, it's not a problem. If you want to move out business logic out of controller action, you can create ServiceObject, it's kind of 'best practice'.

Answer (score 1):

Options 1 and 3 are good enough, definitely not option 2. I'd suggest going with creating a `subscription_service.rb` service file as a form to practice using service modules in Rails.

If you're looking to add another option, you can do the `Subscription` creation in an `after_create` callback in the `Subscriber` model. Do note that you have to pass a virtual attribute into the `Subscriber` model (in this case newsletter_id) so that you have access to it in your model.

#### subscriber.rb

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions

  attr_accessor :newsletter_id

  after_create :create_subscription

  def create_subscription
    Subscription.create(subscriber_id: id, newsletter_id: newsletter_id)
  end
end
```

#### newsletters_controller.rb

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
  def subscribe
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
  end

  private

  def subscriber_params
    params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email, :newsletter_id)
  end
end
```